# ID of sharepoint item

Tags: sharepoint-server

In view we can see the ID of an item which is a integer value.

I just wanted to know in which DataBase and table does the SP stores the ID of this item?
Or does this ID is not maintain in Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint stores all the information about the items of a list in table **AllUserData** which is in the content DB of your site collection which we can find from the central admin of sharepoint.

Refer this nicely written [article](http://adicodes.com/sharepoint-list-internals-with-content-db-details/) on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's stored in the database. It will be stored in your content database of the respective site. Please note that modifications and even reading your content database can be unsupported by Microsoft.

Comment: Could you please specify the table name?

Comment: AllDocs would be where all list/library items are stored

Comment: I misspoke. AllDocs will house documents, where AllUserData, that @nitish mentioned, is where list items are stored.